# How to use Crystal XI to save in the Crystal 8.5 format?

Tags: crystal-reports

I've never had to deal with different Crystal versions before, so I'm hoping someone here would know.

Yesterday, I was contacted by another department.  They had a legacy application using a CR v8.5 template which needed to be edited.  I opened the .rpt file in my Crystal XI Designer, made the changes in about 5 seconds (suppressing a few fields and subsections), and emailed it right back. Of course, the legacy app immediately choked on this new template.

Hence my question, how do I use my CR XI Designer to save this template in the 8.5 format?

I found a possible solution on the internet using some shareware program called Crystal Translator.  But I hesitate to download yet another freeware app to my work computer without some assurance it'll fix the problem. *(Edit: No such luck)*

*(Edit #2: Stay far **far** away from this app. I uninstalled it and it seems to have taken half of Crystal Reports with it.  This is exactly why I don't try out freeware.)*

#### Edit

According to [Downgrade a crystal report to an older version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713844/downgrade-a-crystal-report-to-an-older-version), this simply can't be done.

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Reports does NOT support saving reports in earlier versions.  Your only option is to find a copy of 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I recall (but am not sure) that some years ago, I used CR 10's Save-As function to save in CR 8.5 format.

This post is congruent with my memory.

http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Can_I_save_from_Crystal_XI_to_Crystal_8.5_format%3F.

Comment: The link is dead. Here is an archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130623165712/http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Can_I_save_from_Crystal_XI_to_Crystal_8.5_format%3F It does not agree with what you said. `Crystal XI does not allow you to save reports as version 8.5. This has not been possible since version 9.`