# Delphi 5 & Crystal XI Rel. 2 (RDC) how to?

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports

I'm trying to work with the [class from JosephStyons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378089/how-can-i-display-crystal-xi-reports-inside-a-delphi-2007-application) but I do get an "Invalid Index" Error on the line where the "User ID" should get set.

```
FRpt.Database.Tables[i].ConnectionProperties.Item['User ID'] := edUserName.Text;
```

Here's my environment:

WinXP Sp3, Crystal Reports Developer XI Rel.2 SP4, Delphi 5 Update Pack 1

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated!

Thx,
Reinhard

Comment: What database engine are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value `for [i]` could be the culprit...I can't remember for sure but I believe the first table will be `Table[1]` instead of `Table[0]` as one would expect.

I altered my loop to use:

```
CrTables := CrDatabase.Tables;
for crTableObj in crTables do
```

You might try stepping through the table using a for loop as shown above or by starting with 1 instead of 0.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the hint - changed the loop to:

for i := 1 to FRpt1.Database.Tables.Count do 

but now I get an access violation

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on that line and use Evaluate/Modify.
It will return an error if you try something invalid.

1. Examine `FRpt.Database.Tables[i]` and see if it's valid for what you think are the min and max values for i.
   If `Tables` is an array, one way to avoid that is to use `...Low(Tables) to High(Tables)`
2. If you get your Table Ok, examine `FRpt.Database.Tables[i].ConnectionProperties.Item['User ID']` and see if it's valid.
   It might be that the Item getter does not like the space embedded in "User ID". Some products need either to surround by special characters like "[User ID]", other to replace by an underscore like "User_ID"

Comment: tanks for you input

add 1: there is only one tables object and it's index starts at 1 instead of 0 so the "invalid index" problem has gone.

add2: as you can see, ['User ID'] is already a string with single quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

Are you also setting the password, server name and database name?

```
procedure TReports.LogonToDBTables(cReport:
  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument;
  ConnInfo: ConnectionInfo);
var
  CrDataBase: Database;
  CrTables: Tables;
  CrTableObj: TObject;
  CrTable: Table;
  CrTableLogonInfo: TableLogonInfo;
  iSubReportIndex: smallint;
begin
  CrDataBase := CReport.Database;
  CrTables := CrDatabase.Tables;
  cReport.DataSourceConnections[0].IntegratedSecurity := False;

  for crTableObj in crTables do
    begin
      crTable := CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table(crTableObj);
      crTableLogonInfo := crTable.LogOnInfo;
      crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo := ConnInfo;
      crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
    end;
end;

function TReports.GetConnectionInfo(): ConnectionInfo;
var
  cTemp: ConnectionInfo;
begin
  cTemp := ConnectionInfo.Create();
  cTemp.AllowCustomConnection := True;
  cTemp.ServerName := GetServerName();
  cTemp.DatabaseName := GetDBName();
  cTemp.UserID := GetDBUserID();
  cTemp.Password := GetDBPassword();
  Result := cTemp;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for your input: as for the login I think I have a working solution. the next problem I face is that if i set a parameter which is a stored procedure parameter (shown for parametername = '@P_') the AddCurrentValue function does not set the currentvalue but instead the DefaultValue. How the heck did crystal-businessobjects-sap ever get paid for such a crappy software??

Comment: If you've got time please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073636/crystal-xi-rel2-rdc-parameter-passing

thx

Comment: Are you calling ClearCurrentValueAndRange before trying to set the parameter value?

CRReport.ParameterFields.GetItemByName('ExemplarFee', '').ClearCurrentValueAndRange;

CRReport.ParameterFields.GetItemByName('ExemplarFee', '').AddCurrentValue
  (misVars.Reports.cExemplarFeeAmount);

Comment: yes, since I've saved the report with CR XI I can work with AddCurrentValue but the report preview with CrystalReportsActiveXViewer does not show any data. I've also tried to read SQLQueryString from the Report Object but all I see is that all stored procedure parameters are "NULL". I will give it a few more days but if I can't figure it out until mid next week I will go insane and recommend some other reporting solution to my manager.