# Crystal Reports XI VCL - where is the crpe32.dll?

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports

I've just installed Crystal Reports XI and the Crsystal Reports XI VCL for Delphi.
When I want to create a new Delphi application with an TCrpe - Object, I cant compile it because the crpe32.dll is missing.
Where does this file normally comes from?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you ever get to the point where you can't work with the VCL anymore, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378089/how-can-i-display-crystal-xi-reports-inside-a-delphi-2007-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just searched my complete harddisk, and the files is not (as expected) in the "Program Files\Business Objects", but in "Program Files\Common Files\Business Objects".